# How to sign a Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to sign a Firefox extension. I have search on internet regarding signing the extension and found the URL https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Signing_a_XPI.
I have gone through the instructions given in this site. But could not sign-in the extension. In my case *signtool* and *certutil* commands are not running.

if anyone know the process of signing a Firefox extension then please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

1. Get the credentials from [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/api/key/).
2. Download [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/).
3. Run CMD.
4. Install web-ext using this command:

   npm install --global web-ext
5. Go to your AddOn directory... For Example:

   cd E:\My-Projects\AddOn
6. Run this command:

   web-ext sign --api-key="JWT issuer" --api-secret="JWT secret"
7. A folder with "web-ext-artifacts" name and an XPI file would be created. You can install the XPI!

Answer (score 4):

The document you followed is for old developer-certificate signing and is now obsolete since only Mozilla certificates are allowed now.

1. Get the credentials from [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/addon/api/key/).
2. - if you use `jpm` for SDK development you can just do:

   `jpm sign --api-key ${AMO_API_KEY} --api-secret ${AMO_API_SECRET}`

   - otherwise, sign the `xpi` directly:

   `jpm sign --xpi /path/to/your-addon.xpi --api-key ${AMO_API_KEY} --api-secret ${AMO_API_SECRET}`

Here are some resources to get you going:

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/Addons/Extension_Signing
- https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/11/20/signing-api-now-available/
- https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/12/18/signing-firefox-add-ons-with-jpm-sign/